# checking if a string has a given suffix in c

Tags: c

I would really appreciate help with problem below. I am trying to see whether a string match a suffix. It seems everything is working, but not getting expected result. especially for first test, wondering why it is `false` when `*str == *suffix == '\0'` according to the debugging print statement in solution function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool solution(const char *string, const char *ending);
void test(bool actual, bool expected);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    test(true, solution("abc", "bc"));
    test(false, solution("abc", "d"));
    test(true, solution("abc", ""));
    return 0;
}

bool solution(const char *string, const char *ending)
{   
    const char * str = string;
    const char * suffix = ending;
    while(*str) {
        if (*str == *suffix) {
            suffix++;
        } else {
            suffix = ending;
        }
        str++;
    }
    // print statemet just for debugging
    printf("Before return, str: '%c', suffix: '%c', null: '%c'\n", *str, *suffix, '\0');
    return *str == *suffix == '\0';
}

void test(bool actual, bool expected) {
    if (actual == expected) {
        printf("Success\n");        
    } else if (actual == true) {
        printf("failure: expected true!\n");
    } else {
        printf("failure: expected false!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `*str == *suffix == '\0';`  is not the same as `*str == *suffix && *str == '\0'`.  It very likely does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Unrelated: the output of `test()` on failures is inverted. But it shows correct output because you switched the arguments.

Comment: thanks @WilliamPursell now I see my problem

Answer (score 0):

The biggest hurdle you have to get over in order to compare the end-of-string `'\0'` within your loop -- is not exit the loop when `*str` is `'\0'` (e.g. `0`) BEFORE you have tested the `suffix` and `ending`.

How do you handle cases where you need to fully evaluate a condition inside a loop that you would normally use to control the loop exit? Loop continually and move the exit condition within the body of the loop -- after the needed check has been made. In your case you could do:

```c
bool solution (const char *string, const char *ending)
{   
    const char *str = string;
    const char *suffix = ending;
    
    for (;;) {                          /* loop continually to evaluate end of string */
        if (*str == *suffix) {
            suffix++;
        }
        else {
            suffix = ending;
        }
        str++;
        
        if (!*str && !*suffix) {        /* if at end of both, return true */
            return true;
        }
        else if (!*str) {               /* if at end of str, break, returning false */
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Above after incrementing `str`, the comparison if both `str` and `suffix` are at the end is made. If they are both at end of string, `true` is returned. The exit condition is the `else if()` checking whether `str` has reached the end -- and if so, the loop is broken returning `false`.

The full example would be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool solution (const char *string, const char *ending);
void test (bool actual, bool expected);

int main (void)
{
    test (true, solution("abc", "bc"));
    test (false, solution("abc", "d"));
    test (true, solution("abc", ""));
    
    return 0;
}

bool solution (const char *string, const char *ending)
{   
    const char *str = string;
    const char *suffix = ending;
    
    for (;;) {                          /* loop continually to evaluate end of string */
        if (*str == *suffix) {
            suffix++;
        }
        else {
            suffix = ending;
        }
        str++;
        
        if (!*str && !*suffix) {        /* if at end of both, return true */
            return true;
        }
        else if (!*str) {               /* if at end of str, break, returning false */
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

void test (bool actual, bool expected)
{
    if (actual == expected) {
        printf("Success\n");        
    }
    else if (actual == true) {
        printf("failure: expected true!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("failure: expected false!\n");
    }
}
```

(**note:** your program takes no arguments, so the correct invocation of `main()` is `int main (void)`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/suffix_ending
Success
Success
Success
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Sample incorrect failure `test(true, solution("aaab", "aab"));` here prints "failure: expected true!"

Comment: @chux That does appear to be an Achilles heel of the single-loop. A bandaid (but not robust) solution would be to make the loop `for (size_t count = 0;;) {` and then increment count each time you increment `suffix`, e.g `suffix++, count++;` and then in the `else` use `suffix = ending + count;` which covers  `test (true, solution("aaab", "aab"));`. But the proper solution would either be a nested loop or `strstr()/strlen()`. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

OP's `solution(const char *string, const char *ending)` [fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67129758/checking-if-a-string-has-a-given-suffix-in-c/67132146?noredirect=1#comment118663219_67132146) to re-synchronize properly after a partial match.

A better approach:

```
bool solution(const char *string, const char *ending) {  
  size_t string_len = strlen(string);
  size_t ending_len = strlen(ending);
  if (string_len < ending_len) {
    return false;
  }
  return memcmp(string + (string_len - ending_len), ending, ending_len) == 0;
}
```

---

> why it is false when `*str == *suffix == '\0'`

Use [*str == *suffix && *str == '\0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67129758/checking-if-a-string-has-a-given-suffix-in-c/67135178#comment118658271_67129758).

Comment: I guess this is better solution, discarding chacters from string up to ending size, the only edge case that won't work here is if argument ending is `'\0'`, but that can be easily checked and returning true before other checks

Comment: @MKali  I suspect this works with ending is `""` too.

Comment: my bad, I agree yes, it works with "" too. somehow I get confused